# Two repos sharing folders

Tags: git

I would like to track the following structure.

`d:/framework/` and `d:/framework/content/theme/paper`

In `d:/framework/content/theme/paper` I already have a git repo tracking all files there.

If I git init a repo in `d:/framework/` it will keep telling me

> modified: content/theme/paper (untracked content)

.

The repo in `d:/framework/` should ideally track files and `framework` as well as in `/content/theme/paper` but it does not want to. Even if I remove the .gitignore file from `/content/theme/paper` it does not want to track it.

Ideally I like three separate repos.

1. `framework` including all files and `/content/theme/paper`
2. `framework` including all files and excluding `/content/theme/paper`
3. `d:/framework/content/theme/paper` including all files (this repo I have already)

The repos need to be separate as I need them for gource like that. With branches I am not sure I will see the same result. So how can I get 1. and 2. going please?

Comment: git won't superimpose two repositories on top of each other, you will have to use submodule or subtree functionality to handle this kind of setup, most likely submodule. This will allow you to plug a repository into another repository. The "outer" repository (`d:\framework` in your case) would know that it contains a submodule in `d:\framework\content\theme\paper` but it would not version any of the files in there, instead it would version "which commit is this submodule on".